# Is there a way to launch an app in background in windows phone 8.1....?

Tags: windows, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to launch an app(created myself, registered for a specific uri), from another app, using 
    **Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri, options);** an I was able to do it.

I want set the options such a way that my calling app remains on top. I read that it can be done on windows desktop by setting **LauncherOptions.DesiredRemainingView**
, which is not supported by Windows Phone. Is there any other way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that on Windows Phone. There is only one active app at a time, and it is the one in the foreground.

There are background agents for things like VoIP and music, but that won't do what you want.

Comment: @Peter...What if i Create a background app along with my main app, and register the background app for a specific URI. So when the **LaunchUriAsync(uri, options);** is called , it invokes my background app and I can perform a background task like sending a notification to the action center, without bringing the app to foreground. Is this achievable...?

Comment: No, URIs can only launch foreground apps.